# how to use file (many file's full path inside) as input to MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Hadoop 2.7.1 and coding in Java. I'm able to run a simple mapreduce program where I provide a folder as input to the MapReduce program.

However I want to use a file (full paths are inside ) as input; this file contains all the other files to be processed by the mapper function.

Below is the file content,

```
/allfiles.txt
    - /tmp/aaa/file1.txt
    - /tmp/bbb/file2.txt
    - /tmp/ccc/file3.txt
```

How can I specify the input path to MapReduce program as a file , so that it can start processing each file inside ?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your driver class, you can read in the file, and add each line as a file for input:

```
//Read allfiles.txt and put each line into a List (requires at least Java 1.7)
List<String> files = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("allfiles.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

/Loop through the file names and add them as input
for(String file : files) {
     //This Path is org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path 
     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(file));
}
```

This is assuming that your `allfiles.txt` is local to the node on which your MR job is being run, but it's only a small change if `allfiles.txt` is actually on the HDFS.

I strongly recommended that you check that each file exists on the HDFS before you add it as input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a file with path to other files, you could use [globs](http://blog.zaloni.com/using-globs-and-wildcards-with-mapreduce).

In your example, you could have defined your inputs as `-input /tmp/*/file?.txt`